# What date format use in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, date, format

I have a sqlite table within a column type DATE. Why doesn't this query work? I save my date in this format: `dd-MM-YYYY`

```
SELECT * FROM scadenze where data < strftime ('%d-%m-%Y', '31-03-2017') ;
```

Comment: What is it actually doing?

Comment: The table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Better use `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Using the ISO 8610 format `yyyy-mm-dd` is a good idea anyway. It's the international standard, it sorts correctly, and it's unambiguous. `01-02-2017` could be either January 2 or February 1 (US tends to use month/day, UK tends to use day/month).