# SQLite strftime Group By

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I have a table consisting of a date field and a barcode field; I want the number of barcodes grouped by day for the previous month.

This looked like it would work:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS count,
strftime('%d-%m-%Y',date) AS day
FROM barcodes
WHERE date >= datetime('now', '-1 month')
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

But that gives me incorrect counts. E.g.:

```
341|30-01-2017
274|31-01-2017
288|01-02-2017
332|02-02-2017
224|03-02-2017
35|04-02-2017
1009|06-02-2017
1481|07-02-2017
1626|08-02-2017
507|09-02-2017
428|10-02-2017
125|11-02-2017
1838|13-02-2017
2591|
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM barcodes WHERE date LIKE '2017-02-10%';
579
```

If I do this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS count,
strftime('%d-%m-%Y',date) AS day
FROM barcodes
WHERE date LIKE '2017-02-10%'
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I get:

```
428|10-02-2017
151|
```

So my question is: why is SQLite providing the result as two lines when I use strftime()?

Answer (score 1):

`%d-%m-%Y` is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), so comparisons do not work correctly, and any of the built-in date functions will return NULL.

Comment: Following advice to use %Y-%m-%d <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127128/what-date-format-use-in-sqlite>, I tried:  

    `SELECT MAX(date),  
    COUNT(*) AS count,  
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) AS day  
    FROM barcodes  
    WHERE date LIKE '2017-02-10%'  
    GROUP BY day  
    ORDER BY date ASC;  `

But that still seems to split the count for that day:  

`2017-02-10 16:11:23|428|2017-02-10  
2017-02-10 9:59:06|151|`

Comment: You have invalid dates in the database.

Comment: I think you're correct! For 2017-02-10 I have 151 dates that do not have the hour formatted as a double-digit (no leading zero).

Thank you!